# How do I retrieve data from the View in my Controller.cs

Tags: javascript, c#, controller, sitecore, sitecore8

This is my controller.cs (using Sitecore 8.0)

```
 public class LocationCardController : ComponentsController
    {
        public ActionResult LocationCardControl()
        {
            GetLocationProperty();



            var model = GetDatasource<LocationCard>();
            // Create a new object to represent the center we are searching from
            var mapCenterCoordinates = new LatLng(model.Location.Latitude, model.Location.Longitude);
            model.Location.Distance = Distance.HaversineDistance(mapCenterCoordinates, model.Location.Coordinate, Distance.DistanceUnit.Miles);
            if (model == null) return null;

            return View(model);
        }

        static void GetLocationProperty()
        {
            GeoCoordinateWatcher watcher = new GeoCoordinateWatcher();

            watcher.TryStart(false, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000));
            GeoCoordinate coord = watcher.Position.Location;

        }
    }
```

What I am trying to get is the current location (lat and long) to be inserted into the  "mapCenterCoordinates" variable, apparently I have to use "geolocation" which is in javascript, but I don't know how i can access the "geolocation" parms.

```
var mapCenterCoordinates = new LatLng(model.Location.Latitude, model.Location.Longitude);
            model.Location.Distance = Distance.HaversineDistance(mapCenterCoordinates, model.Location.Coordinate, Distance.DistanceUnit.Miles);
```

Comment: Are you wanting to get the date from a rendering? I am a little confused. You can get it from the Request parameter or create an model with the fields you are sending it. 

Maybe this? http://mhwelander.net/2014/05/30/posting-forms-in-sitecore-mvc-part-2-controller-renderings/

Comment: Thank you for your response ... I am not using a form, I am just trying to use a partial view (controller rendering) ... and pull information that is present in the Main js. I will figure it out. Thanks for you help

Comment: This  should explain it :) http://mhwelander.net/2014/05/28/posting-forms-in-sitecore-mvc-part-1-view-renderings/
http://mhwelander.net/2014/05/30/posting-forms-in-sitecore-mvc-part-2-controller-renderings/